# Calculating data from a linked list and outputting the results into a CSV file in C

Tags: c, printing, linked-list, output

I have created a program in C where a CSV file consisting of coordinates and location IDs is inserted into a linked list. I then:

- find the min and max where the ***x coordinate*** is multiplied with the ID
- find the min and max where the ***y coordinate*** is multiplied with the ID

Now I have to print the 4 calculations, the corresponding location ID and x coordinate into a CSV file.

I have looked at various tutorials on how to do this but they only show methods on how to print unmodified values from the linked list into an output file.

Sorry if this is really confusing. Please comment if you want me to clarify anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 200

struct wake {
    double x, y, u, v, id;
    struct wake *next;
}*head;                                                         

typedef struct wake data;

void read_csv();
void minNode();
void maxNode();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    read_csv();
}

void read_csv() {
    // Opens the CSV datafile
    FILE *fp = fopen("data2.csv", "r");
    
    char buffer[MAX];
    struct wake** tail = &head;
    
    while (fgets(buffer, MAX, fp)) {
        data *node = malloc(sizeof(data));
        node->x = atof(strtok(buffer, ","));
        node->y = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
        node->u = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
        node->v = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
        node->id = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
        node->next = NULL;
        *tail = node;
        tail = &node->next;
  
    }
    minNode();
    maxNode();
}

void minNode() {  
    struct wake *current = head;  
    
    double x_id, y_id;
    //double min;
      
    if(head == NULL) {  
        printf("List is empty \n");  
    }  
    else {  
        //Initializing min with head node data  
        x_id = head->id*head->x;
        y_id = head->id*head->y;
          
        while(current != NULL){  
             //If current node's data is smaller than min  
             //Then, replace value of min with current node's data  
             if(x_id > current->id*current->x) {  
                 x_id = current->id*current->x;
             }
             
             if(y_id > current->id*current->y) {  
                 y_id = current->id*current->y;
             }
             current= current->next;  
        }          
        printf("Min x X id: %lf\n",x_id);  
        printf("Min y X id: %lf\n",y_id); 
    }  
}

void maxNode() {
    struct wake *current = head;  
    
    double x_id, y_id;
    //double min;
      
    if(head == NULL) {  
        printf("List is empty \n");  
    }  
    else {  
        //Initializing min with head node data  
        x_id = head->id*head->x;
        y_id = head->id*head->y;
          
        while(current != NULL){  
             //If current node's data is smaller than min  
             //Then, replace value of min with current node's data  
             if(x_id < current->id*current->x) {  
                 x_id = current->id*current->x;
             }  
             if(y_id < current->id*current->y) {  
                 y_id = current->id*current->y;
             }
             current= current->next;  
        }          
        printf("Max x X id: %lf\n",x_id);  
        printf("Max y X id: %lf\n",y_id); 
    }  
}
```

Here is the input file:

```
19.743748,-11.838155,1.083537,-0.003929,0.947989
19.810734,-11.838155,1.083533,-0.004183,0.947972
19.877850,-11.838155,1.083525,-0.004426,0.947953
19.945097,-11.838155,1.083514,-0.004656,0.947930
20.012476,-11.838155,1.083501,-0.004868,0.947904
20.079988,-11.838155,1.083488,-0.005062,0.947875
20.147631,-11.838155,1.083478,-0.005237,0.947844
20.215405,-11.838155,1.083475,-0.005394,0.947812
```

Comment: So you know how to get unmodified values from the linked list. You probably know how to multiply values. Do you know how to look for min/max? If not find that out. At that point I do not really see what your problem is. Please focus on the specific problem you have.

Comment: My problem is: I have to print the 4 calculations, the corresponding location ID and x coordinate into a CSV file.

Comment: For each of the 4 calculations, how do I then output their corresponding IDs and x coord into the CSV file?

Comment: You do know how to write values to ascii files, don't you? If not find that out first.

Comment: What I am hinting at in total is https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: Look at `fprintf`.